# Xamarin.Forms how to bring app back to foreground? android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin.Forms and I am implementing push notifications. I am receiving the push on both platforms, I can create a toast notification, and I can trigger code on click of the notification.

I'm trying to change the apps page to a specific page when the toast notification is clicked on, which I can successfully do, however if the app is in the background, it changes the page with it in the background and doesn't bring the app back in focus where the user can see it. How can I bring the app back into the foreground?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I bring the app back into the foreground?

You can check the official document: [Starting an Activity from a Notification](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/local_notifications_in_android/#Starting_an_Activity_from_a_Notification).

Basically we need to create a `PendingItent` object and associate it with notification, when user click the notification, Android starts up the activity specified by the `PendingIntent`. And when you build your notification, use the `SetContentIntent` method to include the `PendingItent`:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                              .SetContentIntent (pendingIntent)
                              ...
```

And if you want to navigate to another activity when use tap the notification, you may need to manage the back stack. It is also explained in that document. In addition, you can also check this official sample: [Android Local Notifications Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/LocalNotifications/).

But since you're use XF to build your app, there is only a `MainAcitivty` for android platform, and also you will need to implement this in Android platform and use `DependencyService` to call it from PCL, for example:

In PCL:

```
public interface ISendNotification
{
    void SendLocalNotification();
}
```

In Android platform:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(SendNotification))]

namespace NAMESPACE.Droid
{
    public class SendNotification : ISendNotification
    {
        private static readonly int ButtonClickNotificationId = 1000;
        private Context context = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context;
        private int count;

        public void SendLocalNotification()
        {
            Bundle valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
            valuesForActivity.PutInt("count", count);

            //When use XF, Android has only MainActivity, other pages are all rendered in MainActivity 
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.PutExtras(valuesForActivity);

            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .SetContentTitle("Button Clicked")
                .SetNumber(count)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                .SetContentText(String.Format("The button has been clicked {0} times.", count));

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(ButtonClickNotificationId, builder.Build());

            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

And to navigate to other page, you can use `MessagingCenter` in `MainActivity` for example:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());

    if (Intent.Extras != null)
    {
        int count = Intent.Extras.GetInt("count", -1);

        var navipage = App.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
        var mainpage = navipage.CurrentPage as MainPage;

        MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int>(mainpage, "count", count);
    }
}
```

And in your `MainPage` of PCL navigate to other page:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, int>(this, "count", (sender, arg) =>
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(...);
    });
}
```

By the way, you can call this `SendNotification` for example like this:

```
DependencyService.Get<ISendNotification>().SendLocalNotification();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to bring back the app in the foreground on the page it was before going in the background? Then you I think you would have to know the current page of the application.

If the MainPage property of the App class is a NavigationPage, you can get the current page like this

```
var navPage = App.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
var currentPage = navPage.CurrentPage;
```

Otherwise you could access like that

```
var currentPage;
if (Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 0)
{
    int index = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1;
    currentPage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[index];
}
```

After that when creating the PendingIntent for the notification, you can attach an extra to the Intent, that you will handle in the MainActivity to open a new instance of the page.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.PutExtra("currentpage", currentPage.ToString());
```

And in the MainActivity

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());

    // If the user tapped a notification when the app was in background
    if (Intent.Extras != null)
    {
        string currentPage = Intent.Extras.GetString("currentpage");
        // Handle the opening of the page
    }
}
```

To open the page from the MainActivity, you can simply get once again the current page of the app (which should be the default at this time), and then navigate to the page you want.

I didn't really try it, but I think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Forms.Context.StartActivity((Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity).Intent);
```